# Could the Harry Potter story be replicated with another group of people?

Tags: harry-potter

If the same conditions were set up as it were for Harry's story, would the results be the same?

If a mother sacrificed herself for her son, then someone tried to kill the son, would the result be the same? Would this killer have been withered down to someone without a body? Would the son become a Horcrux?

If so, why is the situation with Harry so important? (Do other parents not sacrifice themselves ect?)
If not, why couldn't this happen?